# What is a sign?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, derrida, foucault

Saussure wrote:

> It is... possible to conceive of a science which studies the role of **signs** as part of social life. It would form part of social psychology, and hence of general psychology. We shall call it semiology (from the Greek semeîon, 'sign'). It would investigate the nature of signs and the laws governing them. Since it does not yet exist, one cannot say for certain that it will exist. But it has a right to exist, a place ready for it in advance. Linguistics is only one branch of this general science. The laws which semiology will discover will be laws applicable in linguistics, and linguistics will thus be assigned to a clearly defined place in the field of human knowledge.

What is a sign in semiotics?

For example can a sign be a myth, as in the structural anthropology of levi-strauss?

Comment: You must read [Charles W. Morris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_W._Morris), [Roland Barthes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_Barthes), [Umberto Eco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umberto_Eco), [Claude Lévi-Strauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_L%C3%A9vi-Strauss) and - of course - C.S.Peirce. The risk is that, according to semiology, "everything is a sign"... and it may be true: if there is a human being "interpreting" it, *it* becomes a *sign*.

Comment: what books of theirs do you suggest?

Comment: Thats a lot to look at - are there book(s) that distills this body of work? After all few go to Newtons *principia* to learn Newtonian Mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must read :

- Claude Lévi-Strauss, 1958, *Anthropologie structurale*, Engl. [Structural Anthropology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/046509516X) and *Anthropologie structurale deux*, 1973, Engl. [Structural Anthropology. Volume II](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226474917); it is mainly dedicated to the structural analysis of *myth*;
- Roland Barthes, *Éléments de sémiologie*, 1964 - Engl : [Elements of Semiology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0374521468); it is quite short, but it is mainly interested into narratology;
- Charles W. Morris, 1971, [Writings on the General Theory of Signs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027919194)
- Umberto Eco, *Trattato di semiotica generale*, 1975 – Engl : [A Theory of Semiotics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0253202175)
- Umberto Eco, Semiotica e filosofia del linguaggio, 1984 – Engl : [Semiotics and the Philosophy of Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0253203988)

and - of course - C.S.Peirce. Unfortunately, *SEP* has only the entry on [Peirce's Theory of Signs](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-semiotics/).

The risk is that, according to semiology, "everything is a sign"... and it may be true: if there is a human being "interpreting" it, it becomes a sign.